# List sort based on another list

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have two generic list objects, in which one contains ids and ordering, and the other a bunch of ids with each id in the second list having an id reference to the first list, for example;

```
public class OptionType
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Ordering { get; set; }
}

public class Option
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Type_ID { get; set; }
}
```

Obviously I can do a simple sort on a list of OptionTypes by doing

```
types_list.OrderBy(x => x.Ordering);
```

Question is though, how could I go about ordering an 'options_list' by utilising the 'Type_ID' on the object which would relate to the ordering of the types_list. As in something like (obviously this isn't valid - but hopefully you will get the idea!)

```
options_list.OrderBy(x => x.Type_ID == types_list.OrderBy(e => e.Ordering));
```

Comment: I don't understand, can you give us a sample of what the sorted output might look like given some input?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should be able to use a join to produce your desired output. Example using query syntax.

```
var orderedOptions = from option in options_list
                     join type in types_list
                     on option.Type_ID equals type.ID
                     orderby type.Ordering
                     select option;
```

Comment: When I use this method, I got `The incoming request has too many parameters` error, what should I do?

Comment: Nailed it. Cheers. I was looking for something similar. Quite often forget about this type of linq syntax :-/

Answer (score 35):

[List.FindIndex()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is your friend when `listA` is small and already sorted:

```
var orderedB = listB.OrderBy(b => listA.FindIndex(a => a.id == b.id));
```

Working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CpLeFU

As @goodeye pointed out in the comments, performance will be a nightmare on larger lists. Use the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3470224/1025555) in that case.

Comment: This is much nicely simpler than the joins. This assumes listA is already sorted in the desired order (type.Ordering). That is, it's using listA's position in the list, not a property of listA. It's also doing multple FindIndex, so may have a performance issue on large lists.

Comment: Man you really saved my day

Answer (score 10):

I like Lambda syntax, so I came up with this equivalent. I can see how query syntax is cleaner for joins.

```
var orderedOptions = options_list
    .Join(
        types_list,
        option => option.Type_ID,
        type => type.ID,
        (option, type) => new { Option = option, Type = type })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Type.Ordering)
    .Select(x => x.Option);
```

For a slight reduction (of what, I'm not sure), this creates the new object with just the Ordering property, instead of the entire Type class. Not much different here, but I had a large class with the sort data, and only need the sorting property. Don't know if it mattered, but it was clearer to read.

```
var orderedOptions = options_list
    .Join(
        types_list,
        option => option.Type_ID,
        type => type.ID,
        (option, type) => new { Option = option, Ordering = type.Ordering })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Ordering)
    .Select(x => x.Option);
```

It looks like the query syntax lets you order within the initial query, while lambda requires ordering after the join creates the new object. Maybe they're really doing the same thing under the covers though: creating the joined object, to be sorted then selected.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a more structured way by implementing the `IComparer` interface with:

```
public class OptionComparer : IComparer<Option>
{
    // <Id, Sort>
    private readonly Dictionary<int, int> _orderedOptionTypeIds;

    public OptionComparer(IEnumerable<OptionType> optionTypes)
    {
        _orderedOptionTypeIds = optionTypes
            .OrderBy(x => x.Ordering) //If its not sorted already
            .ToDictionary(x => x.ID, x => x.Ordering);
    }

    public int Compare(Option x, Option y)
    {
        int xIndex, yIndex;

        if (!_orderedOptionTypeIds.TryGetValue(x.Type_ID, out xIndex))
        {
            xIndex = int.MaxValue;
        }

        if (!_orderedOptionTypeIds.TryGetValue(y.Type_ID, out yIndex))
        {
            yIndex = int.MaxValue;
        }

        return xIndex.CompareTo(yIndex);
    }
}
```

Then the usage may be:

```
IEnumerable<OptionType> optionTypes = Get(...);

options_list.OrderBy(x => x, new OptionComparer(optionTypes));
```

Comment: Nice idea, but *very* resource-intensive because `_orderedOptionTypeIds` will be enumerated twice for each comparison. That could be alleviated somewhat by using a dictionary (id => index), but still, the other solutions are better, resourcewise.

Comment: You are right, I assumed the `_orderedOptionTypeIds` is small enough, (I used it for a fixed small list ~ 10 items), but I've updated the answer for a wider purpose