# Sort one list by another

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

I have 2 list objects, one is just a list of ints, the other is a list of objects but the objects has an ID property.

What i want to do is sort the list of objects by its ID in the same sort order as the list of ints.

Ive been playing around for a while now trying to get it working, so far no joy,

Here is what i have so far...

```
//**************************
//*** Randomize the list ***
//**************************
if (Session["SearchResultsOrder"] != null)
{
    // save the session as a int list
    List<int> IDList = new List<int>((List<int>)Session["SearchResultsOrder"]);
    // the saved list session exists, make sure the list is orded by this
    foreach(var i in IDList)
    {
        SearchData.ReturnedSearchedMembers.OrderBy(x => x.ID == i);
    }
}
else
{
    // before any sorts randomize the results - this mixes it up a bit as before it would order the results by member registration date                        
    List<Member> RandomList = new List<Member>(SearchData.ReturnedSearchedMembers);
    SearchData.ReturnedSearchedMembers = GloballyAvailableMethods.RandomizeGenericList<Member>(RandomList, RandomList.Count).ToList();

    // save the order of these results so they can be restored back during postback
    List<int> SearchResultsOrder = new List<int>();
    SearchData.ReturnedSearchedMembers.ForEach(x => SearchResultsOrder.Add(x.ID));
    Session["SearchResultsOrder"] = SearchResultsOrder;
}
```

The whole point of this is so when a user searches for  members, initially they display in a random order, then if they click page 2, they remain in that order and the next 20 results display.

I have been reading about the ICompare i can use as a parameter in the Linq.OrderBy clause, but i can’t find any simple examples.

I’m hoping for an elegant, very simple LINQ style solution, well I can always hope.

Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered performing a linq join between the two lists then performing a sort?

Comment: Hint: you need to save the original order as a dictionary: id 2 index.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470098/linq-list-sort-based-on-another-list

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Another LINQ-approach:

```
 var orderedByIDList = from i in ids 
                       join o in objectsWithIDs
                       on i equals o.ID
                       select o;
```

Comment: My personal experience is that Linq is in general performing much better than many people think, in most of the cases it's just syntactic sugar executing the same operations as other code in the end, so you will usually not feel the difference.
Actually, for this special case I only know it works, I guess if it is not performing well then you will have to chose a completely different data structure, because this full list join will always take some time, no matter how you do it.

Answer (score 26):

One way of doing it:

```
List<int>  order = ....;
List<Item> items = ....;

Dictionary<int,Item> d = items.ToDictionary(x => x.ID);

List<Item> ordered = order.Select(i => d[i]).ToList();
```

Comment: You are assuming that for each int in the order list, a corresponding Item will exist in the items list...

Comment: `order.Where(d.ContainsKey).Select(...)` or Select/SelectMany with a longer function that uses TryGetValue solves that issue.

Answer (score 15):

Not an answer to this *exact* question, but if you have two *arrays*, there is an overload of `Array.Sort` that takes the array to sort, and an array to use as the 'key'

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85y6y2d3.aspx

> **Array.Sort Method (Array, Array)**
>   Sorts a pair of one-dimensional Array objects (one contains the keys
>   and the other contains the corresponding items) based on the keys in
>   the first Array using the IComparable implementation of each key.

Comment: Any idea how to make this work for lists? I'm here **because** I have to work with lists and can't use this beautiful array sort thing.

Answer (score 9):

`Join` is the best candidate if you want to match on the exact integer (if no match is found you get an empty sequence). If you want to merely get the sort order of the other list (and provided the number of elements in both lists are equal), you can use [Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx).

```
var result = objects.Zip(ints, (o, i) => new { o, i})
                    .OrderBy(x => x.i)
                    .Select(x => x.o);
```

Pretty readable.

Comment: Important note: this requires the `ints` list to be sorted in the first place. The accepted answer does not.

Comment: @Thorarin no I think. Why do you say that? We sort `ints` anyway to get the sort order, so it's not necessary ints have to be ordered in the first place.

Comment: @Thorarin, something else is wrong then. I am sure about my code :)

Comment: It definitely does not solve the problem that the OP describes. Your code never actually evaluates the ID properties of the objects. How can it possibly put stuff in the correct order?

Comment: @Thorarin I made it clear in my answer that `Join` solves one kind of problem. `Zip` is for something else. The title goes by "sort a collection in the order of another collection" and for the vast majority it would imply what I went for in the answer. I just left an alternate answer that might help people with similar problem in future. Of course if sort is based on id, then an appropriate comparer has to be specified as well (in the `OrderBy`)

Answer (score 4):

Here is an extension method which encapsulates [Simon D.'s response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3946021/878701) for lists of any type.

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SortBy<TResult, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TResult> sortItems,
                                                         IEnumerable<TKey> sortKeys,
                                                         Func<TResult, TKey> matchFunc)
{
    return sortKeys.Join(sortItems,
                         k => k,
                         matchFunc,
                         (k, i) => i);
}
```

Usage is something like:

```
var sorted = toSort.SortBy(sortKeys, i => i.Key);
```

Answer (score -1):

`docs = docs.OrderBy(d => docsIds.IndexOf(d.Id)).ToList();`

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.