# Sort List(Of T1) by another List(Of T2)

Tags: vb.net

There are 2 lists. The first is a `List(Of Integer)`, the second is a `List(Of String)`. The first one is sorted in ascending order of size. The second list is to be re-sorted in the same way. *This works with my solution.*

Could someone explain to me what the people in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945935/sort-one-list-by-another) thread have done? I have found many threads about it here but I did not understand some of the solutions. Therefore I wanted to ask, if you can explain this to me. Thanks in advance.

My solution: My idea was to write the integer list sorted to a second integer list and the string list to a second string list. At first, I thought I can use the `IEnumerable`.

```vb
Public NotInheritable Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim IList As New List(Of Integer) From {4, 2, 3, 1, 5}
        Dim NList As New List(Of String) From {"Zacharias", "Cäsar", "Bernd", "Aaron", "Dieter"}
        Dim query As IEnumerable(Of Integer) = IList.OrderBy(Function(x) x)

        Dim IList_s As New List(Of Integer)
        For Each item In query
            IList_s.Add(item)
        Next

        Dim NList_s As New List(Of String)

        For a As Integer = 0 To NList.Count - 1 Step 1 'the new list must offer as many places as the old list.
            NList_s.Add("")
        Next
        For i As Integer = 0 To NList.Count - 1 Step 1
            For j As Integer = 0 To NList.Count - 1 Step 1
                If IList(i) = IList_s(j) Then
                    NList_s(j) = NList(i)
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Are the elements of any of both lists supposed to be unique?

Comment: The solution must be {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} and {"Aaron", "Caesar", "Bernd", "Zacharias", "Dieter"}. So yes, unqiue.

Comment: `NList = NList.Select(Function(x, i) NList(IList(i) - 1)).ToList()`. Order `IList` after. Change the name of `IList` to something else, that name is [already taken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist).

Comment: Use a [Dictionary<TKey, TValue>](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0) then

Comment: Thanks for that, Jimi, and also for pointing out that IList is also an used word. :)

Comment: Note that you can also write it as: `NList = NList.OrderBy(Function(x) IntList(NList.IndexOf(x)) - 1).ToList()`. Possibly, post an answer yourself, so you can explain what you prefer and why.

Comment: Hi Jimi, please excuse my late reply, I haven't looked here in a long time. I prefer your first solution (2:50 p.m.) because that's how I understand best. The IntList is then sorted accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netcore-3.1) the two lists together into a New Type and then Sort by the Number portion:

```
Dim List1 As New List(Of Integer) From {4, 2, 3, 1, 5}
Dim List2 As New List(Of String) From {"Zacharias", "Cäsar", "Bernd", "Aaron", "Dieter"}
Dim Zipped = List1.Zip(List2, Function(Number, Name) New With {Key Number, Key Name}).OrderBy(Function(pair) pair.Number)
For Each pair In Zipped
    Debug.Print(pair.Number & ", " & pair.Name)
Next
```

Output:

```
1, Aaron
2, Cäsar
3, Bernd
4, Zacharias
5, Dieter
```