# Order by string compared to string list

Tags: c#, linq, list, linq-to-sql, dictionary

I'm attempting to order some data using a certain pattern and need some help figuring out how to do so. I haven't seen any examples of using linq queries within an orderby clause and am not exactly sure how to order the data in this scenario:

```
public IList<UserEventModel> GetListData(IDictionary<string, IList<string>> criteria, IEnumerable<UserEventModel> subscriptions)
{
    subscriptions = subscriptions.OrderBy(x => x.EntityType);
}
```

Looking for an extension to append to EntityType to compare against the contents of 'criteria' value pair here at key[2], e.g. `x => x.EntityType.?` (specified collection of values)

Comment: Duplicate of [c# - Linq list sort based on another list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470098/linq-list-sort-based-on-another-list)?

Answer (score 1):

your are almost right. Append tolist and try

```
 subscriptions = subscriptions
                   .OrderBy(x => x.EntityType).ToList();
```