# C# linq to sort list based on rank from another list

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists in C#

```
    var list1 = new List<int>() { 1,2,3,4};

    var list2 = new List<Rank>()
    {
    new Rank {Id = 1, SortOrder = 2},
    new Rank {Id = 2, SortOrder = 3},
    new Rank {Id = 3, SortOrder = 1},
    new Rank {Id = 4, SortOrder = 4}
   };
```

I want to sort list1 according to `SortOrder` in list2

Result

list1 =
3,1,2,4

Is there a way to do this in LINQ?

Comment: LINQ orderBy works on a single list, why don't you merge them and then apply the orderBy clause?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List sort based on another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470098/list-sort-based-on-another-list)

Comment: `list2.OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder).Select(x => list1.FirstOrDefault(y => x.Id == y))`

Answer (score 1):

you can try with `zip`

```
var result = list1.Zip(list2, (l1, l2) => new { l1, l2 })
                  .OrderBy(pair => pair.l2.SortOrder)
                  .Select(pair => pair.l1)
                  .ToList();
```